# Inheriting files from Admin to Standard users

Tags: files, users, sharing, accounts

I am cloning some machines with 16.04 LTS on them, using clonezilla, and I can't figure out how to share/pass files on to another account when it's created.  To be more specific, say I have some files on my desktop and I am in the Admin account and when I set up a new standard account I can't see the files that were on my desktop.  Do I need to place them in the /var folder?  I am still kinda new to Linux and I hope there is an easy solution.

Thanks.

Comment: So from what I understood from your question was that you wanted to share files between an admin and a standard user account. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, in a local setting

Comment: You can run `chmod 777 <file name>` which will anybody to read, write, and execute those files including standard users. If this works for you please let me know because I will Post an answer.